# Angular Module Federation: How to configure isolated routing for each remote module?

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I would like to implement an **isolated routing** for each remote module
of a **Webpack Module-Federation** *Angular* application.

Each remote has its own routing module, but depending on the URL
passed to `router.navigate` or `routerLink`, a remote can override also the base URL which should be exclusively in charge of the host/shell application.

E.g.

- **shell** is exposed at `localhost:4200`
- **remote-a** is exposed at `localhost:4201`
- **remote-b** is exposed at `localhost: 4202`
- **remote-a** is imported by the shell and exposed at `localhost:4200/remote-a`
- **remote-b** is imported by the shell and exposed at `localhost:4200/remote-b`.

What I want:

- each app routing should work both as standalone and as remote;
- `remote-a` should not be able to alter its base URL `localhost:4200/remote-a` when used as a remote;
- `remote-b` should not be able to alter its base URL `localhost:4200/remote-b` when used as a remote;

How can we limit the behaviour of each remote module routing so that it is only able to perform navigation relatively to its own paths,
without allowing it to interfere with the other remotes and the shell/host application?

**Update**

Based on some articles I found

- https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-your-4-steps-guide/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation-tools?activeTab=readme#sub-routes

it seems that the closer solution could be as follows:

> If your Micro Frontend brings its own router, you need to tell your shell that the Micro Frontend will append further segments to the URL. For this, you can go with the startsWith matcher also provided by @angular-architects/module-federation-tools:

```
import { 
    startsWith, 
    WebComponentWrapper, 
    WebComponentWrapperOptions 
} 
from '@angular-architects/module-federation-tools';

[...]

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    [...]
    {
        matcher: startsWith('angular3'),
        component: WebComponentWrapper,
        data: {
            [...]
        } as WebComponentWrapperOptions
    },
    [...]
}
```

> To make this work, the path prefix angular3 used here needs to be used by the Micro Frontend too. As the routing config is just a data structure, you will find ways to add it dynamically.

Could you explain further how this solution works and if it could meet my requirements?

Comment: I don’t think there are actual mechanisms in place that do what you want (yet). However, I guess you could let the host forcefully control some stuff. Best would be to not let remotes control routing directly at all (only by ‘request’ to the host).

Comment: Trying to think of a solution the abstract way (I have not yet a deep knowledge of Angular): would it be possible/easier if each remote had a sort of separate router, without sharing it among the shell and the other remotes? Something like illustrated here https://github.com/kylecannon/angular-dream-stack ?

Comment: This is a possible approach (but still with quite some caveats). Many people in the Angular and MFE world are thinking about how to deal with this correctly and how to get it integrated nicely in Angular (although this is not specifically an Angular problem). We opted to not let remotes control routing at all, but to ship a routing config with every remote that is consumed bu the host. This seems to work out quite well but is obviously not ideal in every situation (for example when remotes also need to work stand-alone).

Comment: Maybe providing a dynamic APP_BASE_HREF for each remote could solve the issure.
https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution depends on how tightly you want to couple your remotes and your shell and where do you want to put the control over the routes and navigation. One approach that I have used successfully is as follows:

- Shell App does not know any details about the remotes it can load, only the MF remote info and a `baseHref` route for each of them.
- Remote Apps dont know anything about a shell, or any other Remotes that might be loaded by the shell
- Only one remote module with routing can be active at any point in time
- (optional) mflib - your shared library for communication between shell and remotes, helper functions etc

**Remote App**
Place the portion of your remote that you want to expose into a dedicated NG Module `FeatureModule`, which imports `RouterModule.forChild` and setups routes for its components.

```
src/app/
     |-app.module.ts  # your main module, - not exposed as mf remote 
     |-feature.module.ts   # your feature module, exposed as mf remote
       |-orders.component.ts
       |-remote-a.component.ts
     ...
```

When you run your `Remote-A` app as standalone app, then you can import your `FeatureModule` eagerly into the main `AppModule` (or lazily, your call depending on use case, if your have more modules etc). If you use standard(eager) import, then you can setup `RouterModule.forRoot` in your root module, to navigate to the components of your `FeatureModule` with whatever paths you want.
If you import lazily, then the routes defined in the `RouterModule.forChild` will be relative to the base path under which this module is lazily loaded to the root router. You need to make sure, that everywhere you navigate inside your feature module, you use relative navigation(for example `this.router.navigate(['items'], { relativeTo: this.route })`).
For example, let say that you have 2 components in your `Remote-A` project and 2 corresponding routes in the `FeatureModule`:

```
const MY_ROUTES =[
{ 
    path: '', 
    component: RemoteAComponent, 
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ 
    path: 'orders', 
    component: OrdersComponent
}
]
```

In eager mode you can setup this routes in `AppModule` via `RouterModule.forRoot(MY_ROUTES)` and then you can use `http://localhost:4201` or `http://localhost:4201/orders` to navigate to those routes(provided you did not set a different BASE_HREF...).
Or, you can use lazy loading to setup those routes as sub-routes of some root path e.g.

```
//app.module.tsm import section:
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'feature',
        loadChildren: () => import('./feature.module').then(m => m.FeatureModule)
    }
])

//feature.module.ts
RouterModule.forChild(MY_ROUTES)
```

Now to access the `OrdersComponent` you would use `http://localhost:4201/feature/orders` as all routes defined in our `FeatureModule` would be relative to(children of) the parent route, in this case `/feature/`

This way, it does not matter under what root URL your `FeatureModule` is loaded, its internal routes will be resolved correctly relative to the root url.

Same for other remotes, make sure you extract the actual remote module into dedicated angular module, with `forChild` router setup.

**Shell:**
You need to define your available remotes somehow - either static config, or dynamically construct it ,e.g by making an HTTP call to some registry endpoint, loading JSON file etc.

```
const microFrontends = [
    {
        baseUrl: "remote-a", //where should we append this to router
        moduleName: "FeatureAModule" //name of NG module class in your remote
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js', //remote webpack url
        remoteName: 'remotea', //name of the remote module, 
        exposedModule: './FeatureAModule', //exposed module inside the webpack remote
    },
    {
        baseUrl: "remote-b",
        moduleName: "FeatureBModule"
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js',
        remoteName: 'remoteb',
        exposedModule: './FeatureBModule',
    }
]
```

Next, you define the routes - both internal to components within your shell app and the routes for remote modules - for remotes you only specify the root path under which the RemoteModule should insert its children route and then you specify `loadChildren` attribute using the `loadRemoteModule` fn from Manfred Steyers `@angular-architects/module-federation` lib. For example:

```
//app.module.ts
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { 
        path: '', //this is an example internal route to component that exists inside shell app
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    //we map each microfrontend entry to a lazy loaded Route object, 
    ...microFrontends.map(mf=> ({
        path: mf.baseUrl, // we insert any routes defined in the remote module we load 
        //as children of `mf.baseUrl` route
        loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule(mf).then(m => m[mf.moduleName])
    }))
])
```

With the example config above, the shell would end up with the following Route tree:

```
/                  -> shell/HomeComponent.ts
/remote-a          -> lazy loaded module FeatureAModule from remote-a remote
    /            -> remote-a/FeatureModule/remote-a.component.ts
    /orders      -> remote-a/FeatureModule/orders.component.ts
```

The shell can mount the remote module under any URL, for example `foobar` and then to navigate to `orders` component form remote-a we would use `/foobar/orders`. So the shell has complete control over the root routes/url structure, and the remote controls the routes/urls within its subtree.

If you ever need to make absolute navigation, or communicate between Shell and Remotes, create a shared angular library, with shared angular module and communicate by a singleton Service (`providedIn: root`).

Right now you can not pass parameters or DI tokens to the remote module when you load it(there is an issue open for this in angular), so if your child/remote module needs to know, under what URL/route it has been mounted, you would need to either naively parse the browser URL and assume that the first segment of the path is your root path, or use a shared service(in shell, when you call `loadChildren`  you can put some values to the service, and in your remote module you can read them)